# foreach loop in while loop with div inside list element

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

hello guys i am trying to make a foreach loop in a while loop. in foreach loop i try to produce list elements with divs inside them but i have very strange output

here is my code

```
$countercat= 0;
$classvar= 1;
echo "<div class='selector-page'>";
echo "<div class='selector'>";
echo "<ul>";
while ($countercat <= 8){
  $stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT eidos, name,  meta_keys, address, telephone, perioxi, st_img, st_open, st_close, lat, longtit FROM magazia WHERE perioxi= :perioxi AND eidos= :eidos  ORDER BY st_id ASC');
$stmt->bindParam(':perioxi', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':eidos', $eidos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$eidos= $c_titles[$countercat]['c_name'];
$stmt->execute();
$allrows=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($allrows as $row) {
  echo "<li>";
  echo "<div class='p". $classvar . " w3-card targetDiv w3-margin-top cardsmar'>";
  echo "<img src='../uploads/" . $row['st_img'] . "' class='cccard' alt='" . $row['name'] . "'";
  echo "<div class='w3-container w3-center'>";
  echo "<h3>" . $row['name'] ."</h3>";
  echo "<p>" . $row['eidos'] . "</p>";
  echo "<p>" . $row['address'] . " , " . $row['perioxi'] . "</p>";
  echo "<p>" . $lang['wrlt'] . " : " . $row['st_open'] . "-" . $row['st_close'] . "</p>";
  echo "<a href='katastimata.php?name=" . $row['name'] . "' role='button' class='w3-button w3-round w3black'>" . $lang['t9'] . "</a><br />";
  echo "<a href='https://www.google.com/maps?q=loc:" . $row['lat'] . "," . $row['longtit'] . "' role='button' class='w3-button w3-round w3-green btnmar'>" . $lang['spot2'] . "</a>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</li>";

}
$countercat++;
$classvar++;

  }
  echo "</ul>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

here is an image from my debugger consonle

[image]

as you see in the image inside in the ul tag exists only one li elemenemt
and the rest of them are out side ul /ul.

my first thought was that is not valid to put div tag in a li tag but this is not true if i use this in the top of my file

DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C// DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/html1-transitional.dtd"
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang:"en"

i am stack here for so long

what am i missing guys?

thanks in advance

vaggelis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Didn't Close the `<img>` tag here.

```
echo "<img src='../uploads/" . $row['st_img'] . "' class='cccard' alt='" . $row['name'] . "'";
```

You Must Close the tag as

```
echo "<img src='../uploads/" . $row['st_img'] . "' class='cccard' alt='" . $row['name'] . "'/>";
```